# Setting remote OSM WMS/WMTS connection in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, openstreetmap, wms, basemap, wmts

I want to set some WMS/WMTS in order to add several basemap (for instance: OSM or other).

I tried to set a new WMS connection:
https://ows.terrestris.de/osm/service?SERVICE=WMS&VERSION=1.1.1&REQUEST=GetCapabilities

But i have an error message:

> connection time out.

Could you tell me how to do? I paste a screen shot.

[image]

Comment: That URL is not a correct WMS URL. Here is a list of OSM WMS services you can use: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/WMS#OSM_WMS_Servers.

Comment: that one is a WMS not a WMTS

Comment: I just edited the post. I have exactly the same error with a WMS connection.

Comment: It works for me, I just specified the URL sans parameters. `https://ows.terrestris.de/osm/service?`   There's no password, I changed the timeouts

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Unfortunatly, still the same error message for me. I do not know what could be the possible sources of error (proxy?).

Comment: Problem fixed. The problem came from our proxy (Tomcat parameters). Thanks.